# Printing out Microsoft SQL data with Python onto a web page

Tags: python, sql, database, flask

I need some helping figuring out why my results are only printing out the last row of data in my table.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request

import pyodbc

#server = 'EVERETT-PC\SQLEXPRESS'
#db = 'AdventureWorks2008R2'

con = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server}',server = 'EVERETT-PC\SQLEXPRESS' , database = 'iNcentDev')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM app.Currency")
s = "<table style= 'border:1px solid red'>"
for rows in cur:
    s = s + "<tr>"
for x in rows:
    s = s + "<td>" + str(x) + "</td>"
s = s + "</tr>"

con.close

app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
  return "<html><body>" + s + "</body></html>"

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[The data I would like to print.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqAGD.png)

[my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVmQI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `fetchall` method.

```
rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    #....
```